# Box expanding CSS <p> element

Tags: css, tinymce

I'm using TinyMCE as texteditor. I'm printing out some text from my database. 
TinyMCE makes my bottom description box to jump because of an "p" element. I want to keep the TinyMCE as it is, not change it to RAW format. I want my box to look a like my other grey boxes.

Image of my problem:
https://i.gyazo.com/8889b7cdab1d25d46fb4c80531234a69.png

```
<div id="container"">
'.$eventinfo['info'].' <--   <p>test</p> is my printout
  <p id="text">
    Description
  </p>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
    #container {
    position: relative;
    background-color:#e9ebee;
    border-radius:4px;
    border: 1px solid #dddfe2;
    padding:11px;
    width:47%;
    margin-top:40px;
    float:left;
    height:auto;
    }

    #text {
    position: absolute;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    left:1px;
    top: -30px;
    float:left;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This question has nothing to do with the P programming language.  Please do not use the [tag:p] tag.

Answer (score 0):

Without code is difficult, but `<p>` probably have value in margin-bottom, so try to add:

```
p#text {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```